# Search Function Textbox not working properly c#

Tags: c#, sql, select, stored-procedures, datagridview

My code:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSearch.Text == "")
            {
                DGViewListItems.Rows.Clear();
                populateTable();
            }
            else
            {
                if (byItemcode.Checked == true)
                {
                    DGViewListItems.Rows.Clear();
                    using (SqlConnection con = db.Connect())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //these Messageboxes is just for testing. to test if the data is correct
                            MessageBox.Show('%' + STEntry.whseFr.Text.Trim() + '%');
                            MessageBox.Show('%' + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + '%');
                            SqlDataReader rd;
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_WhseItemsList", db.Connect());
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "I");
                            switch (activeform.formname)
                            {
                                case "Issuance List":
                                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHSE", STEntry.whseFr.Text);
                                    break;

                                case "Stocks Transfer List":
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHSE", STEntry.whseFr.Text.Trim());
                                    break;

                                case "Stocks Adjustment List":
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WHSE", SADJEntry.txtWhse.Text.Trim());
                                    break;
                            }
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", "");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemcode", '%' + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + '%');
                            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            int i = 0;
                            if (rd.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (rd.Read())
                                {
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows.Add();
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["itemcode"].Value = rd["itemcode"].ToString();
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["whsecode"].Value = rd["whsecode"].ToString();
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["description"].Value = rd["description"].ToString();
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["uom"].Value = rd["uom"].ToString();
                                    DGViewListItems.Rows[i].Cells["quantity"].Value = rd["quantity"].ToString();
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (byDescription.Checked == true)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

This is not working for me, because it does not populate the dgv correctly. I don't think the query is the problem inside the stored procedure, because I tried the query manually and its working fine

The query I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.description, B.uom 
    FROM inventoryTable A  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Items B 
    ON A.itemcode = B.itemcode WHERE (A.whsecode = 'WHSE1' AND A.itemcode LIKE '%S%');
```

The output:

[image]

And here is the output for the code in the textchanged event:

[image]

Here is more example output:
[image]

[image]

This is the stored procedure content for reference:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WhseItemsList] 
    @Action char(5) = '',
    @WHSE char(15) = '',
    @Desc varchar(50) = '',
    @Itemcode char(15) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Action = 'A'
        BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.description, B.uom 
            FROM inventoryTable A  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Items B 
            ON A.itemcode = B.itemcode WHERE A.whsecode = @WHSE;
        END

    IF @Action = 'I'
        BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.description, B.uom 
            FROM inventoryTable A  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Items B 
            ON A.itemcode = B.itemcode WHERE (A.whsecode = @WHSE) AND (A.itemcode LIKE @Itemcode);
        END

    IF @Action = 'D'
        BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.description, B.uom 
            FROM inventoryTable A  
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Items B 
            ON A.itemcode = B.itemcode WHERE (A.whsecode = @WHSE) AND (B.description LIKE @Desc);
        END
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `@Itemcode` is a char(15), which means it always has 15 positions. So this becomes:

`A.itemcode LIKE '%S%            ')`.

And `LIKE` does not ignore trailing spaces, like an `=` would do. So it only matches a value that contains "S" and ends in 12 spaces.

Comment: I added more example, how about those? the LIKE ignored the white spaces. nchar is what you are talking about when it fills out the remaining length, isnt it?

Comment: @RichardJohnson what is the datatype of `itemcode` in the table?

Comment: the datatype of itemcode is nchar. but I've used it many times with no problem until this problem occurred that's why I do not know what's the problem

Comment: its okay now, I changed it to varchar in the stored procedure and now it works. I've been using char until now and this happens so I don't know what happened.